# Problems in exporting terrain from autodesk 3ds

Tags: opengl, animation, models, 3dsmax, antialiasing

i am trying to make small counter strike sort of game and for the terrain part i have exported the terrain in 3ds format from Autodesk 3ds-max and imported the same in opengl using lib3ds. Its working fine but with few problems:

- The terrain is mainly made up of some cubical boxes with texture on them and placed on a big flat surface with boundary wall. In opengl i have enabled anti aliasing but still there is too much aliasing on the boundaries (visible when rotating the camera).
- I have tiled the floor with some image but in opengl it is just the single image stretched over the complete surface.
- I have exported animated model (Skelton+mesh+material+animation) from 3ds and used cal3d library for reading the same. Model has a gun also which is not appearing in opengl and it too has too much of aliasing problem.

I have googled around but couldn't find any relevant solutions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For your antialiasing problem, could it be your hardware settings?

For your tiled texture, instead of using tiling options in max, use the uvw unwrap modifier and scale that face to cover multiple tiles in the Edit box.

As for the last part, you need to provide more information about the problem, screenshots, exporter options, and anything else.